# How to disable 'zoom to rectangle' programatically in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to modify a pan function for matplotlib such that when pressing ctrl+leftbutton I would be able to pan the axes in the figure.

It works well.

The problem is that if the zoom button is pressed, then trying the above would also 'zoom to rectangle' would happen with strange result.

I want to automatically disable the 'zoom to rectangle' button when pressing the 'control' button.

Any ides how this can be accomplished?

Thanks!
Omri

Answer (score 1):

If the window comes from `matplotlib.pyplot` (rather than your own embedding) it will have a tool bar associated with it which you can access via

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
tool_bar = fig.canvas.manager.toolbar
```

You can then set the `mode` attribute to `''` (empty string)

However I suggest caution when doing this because if you change the mode *during* a pan or zoom things may not go well.

Another issue is that `ctrl` does not show up as a normal key, but as a modifier on another mouse or keyboard event (so we can not register a key press event to turn off the zoom).

Instead I suggest you do

```py
if tool_bar.mode != '':
    print("axes panning does not work with zoom enabled!")
    return
```

in your callback.  It leaves it on the user to turn the zoom off, but it will work without having to reach into the (private) internals of the toolbar.

The relevant implementation is at https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/e73d4e056588abc201335d8a491fd9cb37d4c296/lib/matplotlib/backend_bases.py#L2781-L3275